# Correct use of adverb in

Tags: adverbs

How is the following sentence structured and to me it does not seem idiomatic

> The door burst open and **in** they came.

I have a confusion regarding the use of adverb **in** and according to me it should be

> The door burst open and they **came in**.

Am I right?

Comment: I've heard it both ways, and I think they are both correct. Possible duplicate of [This](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/32849/what-is-the-difference-between-in-you-come-come-on-in-and-do-come-in)

Answer (score 1):

"The door burst open and **in** they came." This is inversion - the reversal of a normal order of words. It makes the sentence sound more emphatic and emotional. It's absolutely correct. Do you remember the famous song "Here Comes the Sun" by The Beatles? Well, the sentence is just as correct as "she sun comes here," but it puts more emphasis on "here." If you say "the door burst open and they came **in**," it's OK, of course. You state the fact and you are not particularly emotional about it.

Comment: Can I also say (and in came the people) or (and in the people came)

Comment: @PiyushYadav "in came the people" is fine, but "in the people came..." Then it's not inversion at all because there are two types of inversion: when the verb comes before the subject (in came the people), and when the auxiliary comes before the subject and the rest of the verb phrase follows the subject (e.g. rarely had he seen such a sunset). In "in the people came" the subject comes before the predicate, and that's how we usually build sentences. Now I've remembered another song - "Way Down We Go" - "way down" precedes "we go" and there is more emphasis on "way down."

Comment: @PiyushYadav https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0-7IHOXkiV8